# How to see up and down vote totals

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow, you can click the vote total and it divides into two values: up votes and down votes:

[image]

It doesn't work this way on Programmers (and many other Stack Exchange sites).  Yet, I've observed people talk about the number of up/down votes they've gotten for questions they post here.

How can I see these separated values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing vote counts is one of the perks of the [Established User privilege](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), that's awarded at 1000 rep.

Once you earn the privilege, it'll work the same as on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Is the sole purpose of that to incentivize more participation?

Comment: @roryap That's one of the purposes of privileges, yes. However, specifically for this one, I remember someone mentioning that the query that brings the counts was a bit expensive, so SE limited it to "established users".

Comment: @roryap there's also the "people get too concerned with the actions of others, especially when not as familiar with the site." Its to try to avoid less productive commentary such as "why did this question get 16 down votes?" The belief is that when you have 1000 rep, the answer to that question would be self evident and not need to be asked.